# Jenkins helm installation does not remove plugins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I perform an installation og `jenkins` on GKE, using the official helm [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins).

I initially pass a list of plugins to the corresponding [key](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/jenkins/values.yaml#L215)

```
- plugin1
- plugin2
- plugin3
- plugin4
```

and perform `helm upgrade --recreate-pods --force --tls --install`

I then **take out** some of the plugins from the above list and run the same `helm` command again, e,g, with

```
- plugin1
- plugin2
```

However `jenkins` keeps all the plugins from the initial list.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is an expected behavior.

To change this behavior you should set the parameter `master.overwritePlugins` to `true`.

Example:

```
helm upgrade --set master.overwritePlugins=true --recreate-pods --force --install
```

From Helm chart [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins):

> | `master.overwritePlugins`  |  Overwrite installed plugins on start.  |  `false`   |